# phpmyadmin after insert trigger to delete bots dirty messages is not working

Tags: mysql

i hope someone can help with this super silly question.
I have a web page nogunsdrugsbets.com where I have set a simple comment section where anybody can leave a comment but instead of people commenting (i think i have not many visitors :(), what I have is hundreds of long messages from bots sending me to gay pages, porno or similar. My intention is automate an after insert trigger which deletes any row that has the word 'http' in it, in other words, i kill all the bots' messages because they put url's sending you to other pages.

I don't know much about sql but the below code works when I write in SQL section in each table (affecting all the rows that contain 'http' in the message) but it doesn´t work if I put as a Trigger, instead it blocks all the messages, including the one that don't contain http....
The problem is that I need a trigger because i can't connect constantly to each table to do that everytime, because the bots are writing hundreds of messages all the time. One week i didn't look the page and I found 10000 messages that were blocking the page.

Anyways, the code is simple:

DELETE FROM `commentsmain`
WHERE `message` LIKE '%http%'

[This is the AFTER INSERT Trigger i try to set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/969JR.png)

Here is the complete code of the trigger:

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `spamMain`;CREATE DEFINER=`u956484391_database`@`127.0.0.1` TRIGGER `spamMain` AFTER INSERT ON `commentsmain` FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM `commentsmain` WHERE `message` LIKE '%http%'

Thanks so much.

I have looked all around but I can't find anything that relates to this problem I am experiencing.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to block them from creating the post in your application logic before they even get to the point of inserting in to the database? That way you can handle the logic in the application, such as showing a useful error message or rate-limiting other submissions from the same IP address, email address, or user account.

Comment: Better yet - add a [ReCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/) to the form and prevent the bots from posting altogether.

Comment: Hi TP, thanks for your suggestion, i am gonna try to do that, but if someone is human and sends 10 messages adding url or just say bad words in the message, is good to be able to automatically block them, dont you think?

Comment: @Bronzecat There's no single solution here. Use a ReCaptcha to slow the bots, then use application code to trap bad language, unwanted URLs, etc. Trying to do this at database level is the wrong place. It won't do anything you can't do in your application code and It won't give you much flexibility.

Comment: Thanks TP, you got any idea how I can say in php language that I don't want certain words in my messages? the problem here is i find coding a much more difficult task than finding the 2 lines in sql language, and anyways, we are just telling it 'After Insert' check if it has this words and don't allow, there must be someone that has been there and done that with phpmyadmin or php, but in php seems more tricky. Mysql language is said to be easier than other languages, that's why I want to attack that flank.

Comment: Down below you can see an answer from 'Isaac Bennetch', it says i can't do an After Insert Trigger, but doesn't give a clear alternative. More down below you have the answer from 'Hi Computer, it says i could use Check Constraint but It doesn't offer how to specifically doing it, and when i read the documentation, it throws me messages that you can see below. The thing is, we should be able to restrict or Constrain data from entering into a database BEFORE it enters or even AFTER it enters, in accordance with certain parameters we specify. How to do it? it seems nobody knows.

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete the row you're in the act of inserting as part of an AFTER INSERT trigger.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit more please, So what is the way to do it in your opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Check Constraint](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_check.asp#:%7E:text=The%20CHECK%20constraint%20is%20used,other%20columns%20in%20the%20row.) is what you need

> If you define a CHECK constraint on a column it will allow only certain values for this column.

Comment: Thanks, but do you think I can add a check in phpmyadmin? I really have tried a lot of combinations based on many pages and it is not working... Look I've tried these 2 and many more:

1. ALTER TABLE `commentsmain` 
ADD CHECK (`message` NOT LIKE '%http%');

2. ALTER TABLE `commentsmain` 
ADD CONSTRAINT checkHTTP 
CHECK (`message` NOT LIKE '%http%');

Is this so difficult to add? My nerves are so rocked...